# For Debian-based OSs, where are the launcher shortcuts configured?

Tags: linux-mint, menu, launcher

I spent time installing Signal through the command line yesterday. I run Linux Mint 19.2 Cinnamon.

Without realizing I needed to log out and back in to get Signal to show a shortcut in the start launcher, I spent a bunch of time configuring a `./local/share/applications/` `signal.desktop` file.

I had issues with the configured icon showing in the tray/app panel, and finally tried logging out and back in (it worked!), but then it was showing a duplicate Signal launcher.

When searching "signal" in the start launcher, I saw:

- `Signal (env)`
- `Signal (desktop)`

After deleting the `.desktop` launcher file, Signal still shows in my start launcher.

Question: where does the configuration for the `Signal (env)` launcher live? I've tried looking at env variables and googling about this, but mostly have only found stuff for `.desktop` files.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you installed the package using `sudo apt install signal-desktop` as instructed at signal.org's download page, then there should be another (system-wide) desktop file at `/usr/share/applications/signal-desktop.desktop`.

If you right-click the `Signal (env)` menu item, does it offer any "properties" option or similar? That might tell you more about where it lives.

It looks like Cinnamon has a dedicated menu editor, accessible by right-clicking the Mint icon in the bottom-left corner, selecting `Configure...`, then selecting the Menu tab and clicking on `Open the menu editor`.

Comment: Yeah, that's the wild thing, I checked in `/usr/share/applications/` and there was no signal file in there. Looks like right clicking on the menu item also doesn't give any choices, except options about what to do with the application (add to favorites, uninstall, etc).

Comment: Interestingly, I couldn't install signal using the commands recommended on their website (they were missing the right keychain/fingerprint (idr the correct term)), so I installed the app using `snapd`). Looks like the snap-installed apps have desktop files that live elsewhere, since I found this inspecting Signal through`Open the menu editor`: `env BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT=/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/signal-desktop_signal-desktop.desktop /snap/bin/signal-desktop --no-sandbox %U`. Thanks so much! :D

Comment: I'm too baby to upvote your answer, but I accepted it! :D